# Postgres INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my query, I want to join tables only if the first table's specified column is null. How I can do the join. This is an INNER JOIN and there are 3 tables.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT item_id,item_name
  FROM item i
INNTER JOIN supplier s ON i.item_id=s.items_id
INNER JOIN order O ON O.id=s.req_id
WHERE price>400 AND category='ALL';
```

this join should be available only if the column 'item_order_id' in the item table is NULL. If that column is not null, this join shuold not be done. How can I do in in Postgres (I use  postgres 8).

Comment: add `AND i.item_order_id IS NULL` to the where clause ?

Comment: "*Postgres 8*" covers five major releases (8.0, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3 and 8.4) - you should state your exact version. Also note that only 8.4 is still supported (but only for a few more months) so you should really plan an upgrade to a current (e.g. 9.3) release.

Comment: I use  8.0.3. versioning upgrade can be a good idea. but for my system environment I have to keep current version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1. Put the condition in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT item_id,item_name
  FROM item i
INNER JOIN supplier s ON i.item_id=s.items_id
INNER JOIN order O ON O.id=s.req_id
WHERE price>400 AND category='ALL' AND i.item_order_id IS NULL;
```

Option 2. Put the condition in the join:

```
SELECT item_id,item_name
  FROM item i
INNER JOIN supplier s ON i.item_id=s.items_id AND i.item_order_id IS NULL
INNER JOIN order O ON O.id=s.req_id
WHERE price>400 AND category='ALL' ;
```

Comment: thanks for reply. How ever,I am using this query inside a function. This join should be happened only if the item_order_id is null. Can't we put this joining inside the where clause ? I means some thing like this, inside the function and in the where clause  CASE 
                when item_order_id IS NULL ..

Comment: I don't understand what your concern is. Option 2 joins only those records where item_order_id is null. Both options produce the same result. There may be performance issues, so if that is your concern you should check the explain plan for both options (against fully loaded tables).

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: no there are no performance issues. The two queries will generate exactly the same plan(s).